# laravel orderByRaw() on the query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

there is no way to make such a query(**with the binding**) using the Laravel query builder right now:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE MATCH( `title`, `description` AGAINST( 'bar' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) ORDER BY (MATCH( 'title' AGAINST( 'bar' )) DESC;
```

this will order the results by relevance, If we had(which we don't now!) orderByRaw then the above query would be:

```
Post::whereRaw("MATCH( `title`, `description` AGAINST( ? IN BOOLEAN MODE))", array('bar'))->orderByRaw("(MATCH( 'title' AGAINST( ? )) DESC", array('bar'))->get();
```

I opened this issue but It didn't get anywhere:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2134

any suggestion?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Using Eloquent you can do the following:

```php
$match = "
    match (
        `title`,
        `description`
    ) against (
        ?
        IN BOOLEAN MODE
    )";

$against = 'bar';

$sql->whereRaw($match, array($against));
$sql->orderByRaw($match . " DESC", array($against));
```

The same would work with the Query Builder, but then you have to do a little rewriting.

Comment: it seems orderByRaw is implemented in the latest version.

Comment: I didn't look at the Query Builder, but Eloquent really supports this for a long time now. I have used it for months on Laravel 4.0.*.

Comment: Eloquent use the same Query\Builder class for it's queries.

Comment: @Amir: Eloquent uses the QueryBuilder, but the QueryBuilder does not use Eloquent.

Comment: http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2015/02/laravel-quick-tip-order-by-raw shows how to use orderByRaw with FIELD, which is practically the same thing