# How to order by using appended attribute in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-4

I created an appends attribute in Laravel Model, from the code below.

```
    protected $appends = array('total'=>'');
```

And I set the returned value.

```
    public function getTotalAttribute(){
           return ProductPart::where('product_id',$this->id)->count();
    }
```

Then I want to order records from database by using `total` attribute

I tried to use `Product::orderBy('total','desc')->get()` but it didn't work.

Does anybody has some suggestions to this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

the orderBy takes an actual database field not an appended one

try this

```
$products = Product::all();
$products = $products->sortBy(function($product){
    return $product->total;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's awesome and I tried to reverse the result by using `return -$product->total` it works too.

Comment: It seemed to work and voted up, but after a few tries it doesn't really seem to. once you have the Collection, sortBy seems to have no effect either with a closure nor via sorting the collection through the append attribute (which does appear in each object in the collection). It looks like it might be an issue with Collections who disregard the appended values as they end up in a different array from the "real" attributes. can't remove my upvote though since I'd need to edit the answer but can't offer any insight except sorting it through php.

Comment: Have you find any solution to this problem? @RedSash

Comment: Try to use laravel custom pagination

Answer (score 2):

If working with attributes those are not always available instantly (e.g. for freshly created models).

As expansion on Ayobami Opeyemi's answer you should be able to use Collection's sortBy if you force the attribute to evaluate by calling its function directly:

```
$products = Product::all();
$products = $products->sortBy(function($product){
    return $product->getTotalAttribute();
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-sortby

Answer (score 2):

use `sortBy` for **ASC**

```
$collection->sortBy('field');
```

use `sortByDesc` for **DESC**

```
$collection->sortByDesc('field');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sortBy](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-sortby) method from collections.

```
$products = Product::all();
$products = $products->sortBy('total');
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please include a brief description of how this code solves the problem.

Comment: This works if you're using `all()`, but it breaks if you use pagination.

Comment: @ceejayoz
The question did not specified that the returned records were paginated. Indeed you cannot paginate a collection. The following gist has an implementation for this.

https://gist.github.com/simonhamp/549e8821946e2c40a617c85d2cf5af5e

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the proposed solution using a `sortBy()` callback does not work with paging.
Here is an alternative to the accepted solution:

## orderByRaw()

If the appended attributes can be calculated from the fields in your query you can instead use `orderByRaw()`, like so:

```php
// For example, booking percentage
$query->orderByRaw('bookings_count / total_count');
```

Check out a more advanced example here:
[laravel orderByRaw() on the query builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065972/laravel-orderbyraw-on-the-query-builder)

Answer (score 0):

This my example using attributes:

```
$collectionCenters = Supplier::where('supplier_type','=','persona_juridica')->get();
// Ordenar de forma descendente las cantidades
if ($this->unit == "kg") {
    $collectionCenters = $collectionCenters->sortByDesc(function($cc) {
        return $cc->qty_sold_kg;
    });
}
if ($this->unit == "t") {
    $collectionCenters = $collectionCenters->sortByDesc(function($cc){
        return $cc->qty_sold_tons;
    });
}
```

Then in my blade I jus call the attribute:

```
<td>
    @if($unit == "kg")
        {{ $cc->qty_sold_kg }}
    @elseif($unit == "t")
        {{ $cc->qty_sold_tons }}
    @endif
</td>
<td>{{ $cc->details->ruc }}</td>
<td>{{ $cc->details->companyName }}</td>
```