# Laravel Sort appends Date with pagination

Tags: php, laravel

My code here sort pagination by dateOrder of and dateOrder is in My Model appends  How Can i sort all result not every 30 record

```
$posts = Post::paginate(30)->sortByDesc('dateOrder');



protected $appends =['dateOrder'];

public function getdateOrderAttribute()
{
    if($this->add_date && is_null($this->updated_at)  )
        return Carbon::createFromTimestamp($this->add_date)->toDateTimeString();

    return ($this->updated_at)->toDateTimeString();

}
```

Comment: Sort it before you paginate it? `$posts = Post::sortByDesc('dateOrder').>paginate(30);`

Comment: try `Post::orderBy('dateOrder','desc')->paginate(30)`

Comment: @Qirel I tried and I get error  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sortByDesc()

Comment: Use `sortBy("dateOrder", "desc")` instead then.

Comment: @VibhaChosla tried and get error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dateOrder' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `posts` where `posts`.`deleted_at` is null order by `dateOrder` desc limit 30 offset 0)

Comment: `dateOrder` is column name of or anything else??

Comment: on which database field you want to apply sorting ?

Comment: @kareemelsharkawy What do you mean by `dateOrder is in My Model appends`

Comment: @VibhaChosla it's not a field it's   in $appends

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya I have update my question

Comment: @kerbholz I'm using dateOrder by model appends

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050476/how-to-order-by-using-appended-attribute-in-laravel
may be you get some idea

Comment: @kerbholz add_date is formated in  database  like this 1503149895

Comment: @kareemelsharkawy You should use `Post::paginate(30)->sortByDesc('date_order');`

Answer (score -1):

Try below code for that:

```
$posts = Post::paginate(30)->sortByDesc('date_order');



protected $appends =['dateOrder'];

public function getdateOrderAttribute()
{
    if($this->add_date && is_null($this->updated_at)  ){
        return Carbon::createFromTimestamp($this->add_date)->toDateTimeString();
    } else {
        return $this->updated_at->toDateTimeString();
    }

}
```

I hop it will help..