# Laravel alternative to paginate on collection?

Tags: laravel

On my website, I have Submissions, and submissions can have comments.

Comments can have upvotes and downvotes, leading to a total "score" for the comment.

In this example, before passing the comments to the view, I sort them by score.

```
$comments = Comment::where('submission_id', $submission->id)->where('parent_id', NULL)->get();

$comments = $comments->sortByDesc(function($comment){
    return count($comment['upvotes']) - count($comment['downvotes']);
});
```

This works fine. The higher the score of a comment, the higher it is sorted.

However, I want to paginate these results.

If I do `->paginate(10)` instead `get()`, the following `sortByDesc` will only sort those 10 results.

So logically I would want to add the paginator after the `sortByDesc` like so:

```
$comments = $comments->sortByDesc(function($comment){
    return count($comment['upvotes']) - count($comment['downvotes']);
})->paginate(10);
```

However this will return the error:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not
>   exist.

as expected.

My question is, what is the alternative to using paginate in this situation?

**EDIT:**

When trying the response of @party-ring (and switching the double quotes and single quotes) I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '["upvotes"])
>   - count($comment["downvotes"]) desc limit 10 offset 0' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `comments` where `submission_id` = 1 and `parent_id` is
>   null order by count($comment["upvotes"]) -
>   count($comment["downvotes"]) desc limit 10 offset 0)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$comments = Comment::where('submission_id', $submission->id)
    ->where('parent_id', NULL)
    ->orderBy(DB::raw("count($comment['upvotes']) - count($comment['downvotes'])"), 'desc')
    ->paginate(10);`
```

SortBy returns a Collection, whereas you can only call paginate on an instance of QueryBuilder. OrderBy should return an instance of QueryBuilder, and you should be able to do the subtraction using a `DB::raw` statement.

** edit

I have just read about `orderByRaw`, which might be useful in this scenario:

```
$comments = Comment::where('submission_id', $submission->id)
    ->where('parent_id', NULL)
    ->orderByRaw('(upvotes - downvotes) desc')
    ->paginate(10);`
```

You might have to play around a bit with your subtraction above as I don't know the structure of your comments table.

A couple of links which might be useful:

- [laravel orderByRaw() on the query builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065972/laravel-orderbyraw-on-the-query-builder)
- https://laraveldaily.com/know-orderbyraw-eloquent/

Comment: this returns: syntax error, unexpected ''. However I switched the double quotes with single quotes and single quotes with double quotes and it returns a different error. I'll make an edit to the main post.

Comment: @FelixMaxime how are you getting on? When you use single quotes, it won't be able to pass the value of the variables into your SQL statement, so it doesn't understand what you mean by `$comment` because it is being treated as a string and not a variable. Apparently there's a function called orderByRaw which you may be able to use, will update my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to paginate after the get, the solution i try on my website is this and it works

```
$users = User::where('votes', '>', 100)->get();

$page = Input::get('page', 1); // Get the ?page=1 from the url
$perPage = 15; // Number of items per page
$offset = ($page * $perPage) - $perPage;

return new LengthAwarePaginator(
    array_slice($users->toArray(), $offset, $perPage, true), // Only grab the items we need
    count($users), // Total items
    $perPage, // Items per page
    $page, // Current page
    ['path' => $request->url(), 'query' => $request->query()] // We need this so we can keep all old query parameters from the url
);
```

Comment: When you are working with laravel pagination in your url you get the query **?page=1**  depending of the page that you are looking for, with **input** you can get the value of the parameter **page**

Answer (score 0):

You could add a macro:

```
if (!Collection::hasMacro('paginate')) {
    Collection::macro('paginate', function ($perPage = 25, $page = null, $options = []) {
        $options['path'] = $options['path'] ?? request()->path();
        $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
        return new LengthAwarePaginator(
            $this->forPage($page, $perPage)->values(),
            $this->count(),
            $perPage,
            $page,
            $options
        );
    });
}
```

Then you can use a collection to paginate your items:

```
collect([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])->paginate(5);
```

See **Extending Collections** under [Introduction](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#introduction)